# SKMaps: How to search an address directly?

Tags: android, search, skmaps

I'm trying to develop an activity in android that allows the user to search an address in offline maps.I currently use multistepSearch with SKMultiStepSearchSettings but inspecting the documentation I have found the following class: **SKAddressSearchSettings** [Link](http://developer.skobbler.com/docs/android/index.html?com/skobbler/ngx/search/class-use/SKAddressSearchSettings.html).

Due to the search step by step is a bit tedious for the user, my question is as follows:

Is there any way to use this class to perform a search for an address directly without search step by step ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, multi step search - where you enter the country, city & street in a sequence - is the only supported way of geocoding.

One line search - writing the entire search query in one line of text, i.e. "Berlin, Alexander Platz, 14B" - is not supported at the moment.

It is on the roadmap and will likely be available late 2015 or early 2016.

Comment: What about this one http://developer.skobbler.com/docs/android/2.1.0/com/skobbler/ngx/search/SKOnelineSearchSettings.html ?

Comment: experimental class - left over from our first attempts at "one line search" (should have been removed from the public SDK)

Comment: @Ando Looks like simple online search like "Berlin" using `SKMultiStepSearchSettings` doesn't work too?